# Trying to find the unix epoch time code for 12 hours from now()

Tags: datetime, schedule

I have a scheduled class to run every night at 10pm. I would like to; at the end of that job have it send the time code for 12 hours from whenever that job was running.

```
public class mailScheduler {
// these are to compose the final endpoint
public static string endpointa = '/campaign/{';
public static string endpointb = '}/schedules';
public static string endpoint {get; set;}

// string to hold callout body and verb
public static string jsonBody {get; set;}
public static string httpMethod = 'POST';

// custom label containing all the campaign id numbers
string eoCamp = system.label.Emain_Only_Campaigns;

// unix epoch var
long longtime {get; set;}

// map to constuct json
static List<Map<String, Object>> jsonMAP = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

public void sendIt(){

            //split the custom label
            List<String> labelStr = eoCamp.split(',');

            //put it into List<Integer>
            List<Integer> campids = new List<Integer>();
            for(String str:labelStr)
            {
                campids.add(Integer.valueOf(str.trim())); //mind to 
trim() the String, otherwise you will receive error.
            }
    for(integer i : campids){
            endpoint= endpointa + i + endpointb; 
            SYSTEM.debug('endoint=' + endpoint);

            DateTime myDateTime = datetime.now(); 
            system.debug('mytime=' + myDateTime);

            myDateTime= myDateTime.addHours(12); 
            system.debug('mytime+12='+mydatetime);

            longtime= myDateTime.getTime(); system.debug(longtime);
                Map<String, Object> mapped = new Map<String, Object>{ 
                    'send_at'=> longtime};
                         jsonMAP.add(mapped); 
            system.debug(mapped);}

           jsonbody = JSON.serialize(jsonMAP);

        SendGridAPI.sendRequest(jsonBody, endpoint, 
    httpMethod);system.debug(jsonBody);

  }
}
```

Comment: well, the `Datetime`, `addHours(12)`, and `getTime()` that you have certainly accomplish what you are describing. Can you elaborate on what isn't working here?

Comment: I was having a hard time validating the info, and my callouts returned 404 errors. I have since been able to correct the code to be in seconds not milliseconds. By dividing longtime/1000. and I am not sure about anything else.